# How to receive from server object with message

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

My service method for creating products looks like below:

```
    create(newProduct: Product): Promise<Product> {
        return this.http
            .post(this.productsUrl, JSON.stringify(newProduct), {headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Product)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

but now JSON from server has only fields of product:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Name"
}
```

And now I want to send from server a json which will contain a product and message:

```
{
   "product": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Name"
   },
   "message": "Operation was successful"
}
```

But I don't know how to retrieve object and message in service from server.

Comment: There is no difference here in your service.  It is going to pass that entire JSON object back to whatever calls your `create` function. Then you will handle the JSON there as to what to do with the information. But the JSON should be sent in it's entirety regardless of what content is in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two classes, one for product details and one for the Post call's response.

```
export class Product{
    id:string;
    number:string;
}

export class PostResponse{
    product:Product;
    message:string;
}
```

Now, in your post call, you can do 'Promise< PostResponse >' instead of 'Promise< Product >' to retrieve the response object.

Answer (score 0):

you can observable `map` operator.

```
create(newProduct: Product): Promise<Product> {
        return this.http
            .post(this.productsUrl, JSON.stringify(newProduct), {headers: this.headers})
             .map((res: Response) => {
                       let data= res.json();
                       return data.product;
                   })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Product)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```